# What is the fastest way to put a large amount of data on a local file system onto a distributed store?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, etl, distributed-computing, bigdata

I have a single local directory on the order of 1 terabyte. It is made up of millions of very small text documents. If I were to iterate through each file sequentially for my ETL, it would take days. What would be the fastest way for me to perform ETL on this data, ultimately loading it onto a distributed store like hdfs or a redis cluster?

Comment: Could you please give more details, as in what ETL tools you are using, what kind of operation you want to do what you text documents.

Answer (score 0):

Generically:  try to use several/many parallel asynchronous streams, one per file.  How many will depend on several factors (number of destination endpoints, disk IO for traversing/reading data, network buffers, errors and latency...)